# Time tracking from within an IDE

Tags: ide, time-tracking

I would like to track how much time is spent on each project within my IDE.  For as long as I've been developing, I've used a standalone application or even a web application.  I would like it to tie into the IDE directly because it will automatically track time spent based on the open project / file (ideally).

I started to read about **TimeKeeper** for Netbeans.  What else works well ... for free?

Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good experiences with http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/ for eclipse

Also, the commercial extension of mylyn, TaskTop has a number of interesting features such as task-specific desktops and breakdown of hours spent / bug, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like what I would want as well.  Just knowing the number of hours per project isn't as detailed as I'd like.  I would like it to be broken down by bugs or feature enhancements if possible.  It integrates with trac which is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

Check out WakaTime for NetBeans. It's open-source on GitHub, and completely automatic:

https://github.com/wakatime/netbeans-wakatime